# Angular 2 child component loads before data passed with @input()

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have two component in my angular 2 application : component A (parent) and component B (child).

When i passe data (myData) from A to B with @Input() i get my data in my B (child component), but the problem is that the child component loads BEFORE myData and i got indefined, the only way a can console.log(myData) is in ngOnDestroy hook !

How to deal with this kind of load order ?

Comment: try to load the data in the constructor of the component

Comment: It's unclear why this causes problems. You can use the lifecycle hooks `ngOnChanges()` which is called every time the `@Input()` is updated from the outside. `ngOnInit()` is called after the first time `ngOnChanges()` is called. If that doesn't work then please provide more code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. I can't now what's going on on your site without seeing the code.

Answer (score 13):

Use `*ngIf` in your parent component to delay the initialization of the child component. You will bind the child component only if `myData` has a value.

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component [input]="myData" *ngIf="myData"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use a `*ngIf` in your parent like

```
< child-component *ngIf="myData" > </child-component>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can find good example to do it in example project 
[here.](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)

Check `app.service.ts` code.

You need to describe global service that will store your data that will be shared between components.