# Angular component isnt passing data before the child component is loaded

Tags: javascript, angular

In my code, I have a component that holds all the data retrieved from firebase. Including a variable called "currentTurnName" which gets passed from the parent to the child component. That variable is used to render a  twitch channel inside the child component but doesn't update when the data changes.. I followed a few stack overflow guide that talk about using the *ngIf directive like <childComponent *ngIf"currentTurnName"> to stop the child component from loading until the data is retrieved- it works on page load, except it doesn't work when that variable is passed in new data asynchronously.

**Child Component**

```
  export class TwitchVideoComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { 
  }

  player: any;
  @Input() currentTurnName: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
      var options = {
        width: 1080,
        height: 720,
        channel: this.currentTurnName,
      };
      this.player = new Twitch.Player("<player div ID>", options)
      this.player.setVolume(0.5);
      console.log(this.currentTurnName);
  }
//  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
//    if (this.currentTurnName) {
//     this.player.setChannel(this.currentTurnName);
//    }
//  }
}
```

Child Template

> ```
>  <div id="<player div ID>" class="twitch"></div>
> ```

**Parent component**

```
  export class GameRoomComponent implements OnInit {
  public  users$: Observable<User[]>
  currentUser: Observable<CurrentUser[]>;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService, private afs: AngularFirestore) { 
    this.currentTurn = afs.collection<CurrentUser>('currentPlayerDB').valueChanges().pipe(
      tap(res => {
        this.currentTurnName = res[0].user;
        console.log(this.currentTurnName);
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
  currentTurn: any;
  items: any;
  currentTurnName : any;
```

**Parent Template**

> <app-twitch-video *ngIf="currentTurnName"
> [currentTurnName]="currentTurnName" >

This somewhat talks about my issue, but mine is more complex considering the data is changed
[Angular 2 child component loads before data passed with @input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147356/angular-2-child-component-loads-before-data-passed-with-input)

Comment: console.log(this.currentTurnName); Does it log value of currentTurnName?

Comment: So the commented out ngOnChanges doesn’t work either..? What do the console.logs show?

Comment: There are some relevant parts of your code which are missing from the example. Could you flesh it out a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Angular's property setters.  The documentation can be found here in this section (Intercept input property changes with a setter): https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Here is a snippet using your code:

```
export class TwitchVideoComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor() {}

 player: any;

 @Input() set currentTurnName(name) {
   this._currentTurnName = name;
   console.log('This should fire every time this Input updates', this._currentTurnName);
   if (this._currentTurnName) {
    this.player.setChannel(this._currentTurnName);
   }
 }

 public _currentTurnName: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var options = {
      width: 1080,
      height: 720,
      channel: this._currentTurnName,
    };
    this.player = new Twitch.Player("<player div ID>", options)
    this.player.setVolume(0.5);
    console.log(this._currentTurnName);
  }
}
```